# PHP Timestampable - update and create for one single field, possible?

Tags: php, doctrine-extensions

I have two fields in my entity - $creationDate and $lastUpdate, which I am updating with the help of:

```
 @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="create")
```

and respectively.

```
 @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="update")
```

However, I would like to limit it to one single field. My question is whether there is anything like

```
 @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="create, update")
```

I searched for some online tips on whether it's possible, but failed to identify a workable solution.

Comment: Have you tried using the `"change"` trigger?

Comment: I am on it for the last couple of hours, fighting with an issue - "Missing parameters on property - fieldName, field must be set on [change] trigger in class". So far could not achieve any result.

Comment: With `"change"` trigger, `field` argument is required. Simply pass a list of field names as follows: `@Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field={"field1", "field2"})`. AFAIK, there is no way to instruct Timestampable to include all fields, so the code is going to be a little bit verbose :-/

Comment: Thanks for advice, Ruslan! Already tried it, I get "Timestampable extension does not support multiple value changeset detection yet.", though yes, the error in case is solved by the introduction of the field value.

Comment: Please answer separately so that I could mark your answer as the right one. Pitifully, after solving one problem immediately two appear ) Looks like I will have a problem with this Doctrine feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `Timestampable` annotation from [Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) repository supports only three types of triggers: `create`, `update`, and `change`. With the `change` trigger you can achieve something similar to what you describe as follows:

```
@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(
    on="change",
    field={"field1", "field2"}
)
```

where `field` specifies a list of tracked fields. Unfortunately, there is no way to instruct `Timestampable` to track all fields implicitly.

Comment: Actually, as practice has shown, there is absolutely no need to do anything. "update" works on creation as well.